# how to calculate date if less than a year show month if less than a month show days?

Tags: php

My question is  how to calculate date if less than a year show month if less than a month show days ?

here is what I have:

```
$registered_date = new DateTime($Created_at);
$current_time = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d, H:i:s'));
$interval = $registered_date->diff($current_time);
echo "<span>".$interval->format('%d Day <br> %m Month <br> %Y Year')."</span>";
```

My code shows date like:

```
12 days 3 months 1 year
```

But I want to show user registered date on profile like this:

if older than a year then show only year: `1 year`.

if less than a year then show months: `3 months`.

if less than a month then show days: `10 days`.

Comment: Add a condition to check if year is zero, show months and if month is zero show days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$registered_date = new DateTime('28-10-2017');
$current_time = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d, H:i:s'));
$interval = $registered_date->diff($current_time);
//echo "<span>".$interval->format('%d Day <br> %m Month <br> %Y Year')."</span>";
list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $interval->format('%Y-%m-%d'));

if($y > 0)
    echo $y .' year';
elseif ($m> 0)
    echo $m .' month';
else
    echo $d .' day';
```

Comment: @highlan, it's good that you answered but you should let OP try out things for his own good and betterment rather than spoon feeding. These are basics which OP can try out through reference links.